# how to update data from a table to store results in another

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption, copy, sql-insert

How can I copy a table to another while changing some values ?

I mean for example something like :

```
perso=# create table chk ( id serial primary key, Q text , R  text not null unique, p text not null unique) ; 
CREATE TABLE
perso=# select * from chk
perso-# ;
 id | q | r | p 
----+---+---+---
(0 rows)
```

as a destination

an I would use datas from

```
perso=# select * from tmp                                                                                     
;
 idt | qt | rt | pt 
-----+----+----+----
```

I want to copy data from tmp table to chk table and at once if possible update data on chk so
chk.p is equal to  tmp.t  with `crypt('t', gen_salt('bf'))`

I tried to copy with subselecting but I got so many different types of errors ...  I just can't explain nor paste them all here.

short ask : update data from a table to store results in another

I guess the good way should be to do something like :

```
update chk 
set 
   ......
from tmp  (colums, crypt('t', gen_salt('bf'))
....
```

but how ?

Answer (score 1):

To copy rows from one table to another, you can use `insert ... select`. This is a very flexible syntax (the `select` part may use all the features that a regular `select` query can), which lets you do what you want in a simple manner:

```
insert into chk (id, q, r, p)
select idt, dt, rt, crypt('t', gen_salt('bf')) 
from tmp
```

In case you wanted to update the original table:

```
update tmp set pt = crypt('t', gen_salt('bf')) ;
```

Comment: Thanks I understand now

Comment: And Then how to decrypt a row from that column after  ?

Comment: @francoisP: that's a really different question. I don't think that `crypt()` goes both ways, since it is a password hashing function - and those are usually designed to prevent a reverse algorithm. You can, however, compare a crypted value against a non-encrypted value. You might want to have a look at [the pgcrypto documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html).

Comment: ok cool so that means it is secure for my need if cannot be read this way. I will another database for pgp_sym_encrypt & pgp_sym_decrypt so I can separate both access modes.